# php - Advice on how to get every synonym variation for string of words?

Tags: php

So I have a string

```
$string = "funny cat fighting";
```

and I have a 2d array of synonyms such as:

```
$arr = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'cat',
    1 => 'tabby',
    2 => 'kitty',
    3 => 'puss'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'funny',
    1 => 'haha',
    2 => 'lol'
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'war',
    1 => 'fighting'
  )
)
```

How would I go about getting every possible synonym variation of `$string "funny cat fighting"`, for example I'd want the output to be an array of strings:

```
funny cat fighting
haha cat fighting
lol cat fighting
funny tabby fighting
```

...all variations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Presuming a couple of things:**

- Your **not** looking for every permutation of every word, which then makes no sense with using a matching string.
- The array is structured slightly wrong as `cat` is in the first array and `funny` is in the second.

Ok, so with a little tweaking to your array, it can easily be done like the following, I've added that if the word is not in the array then it stays the same:

```
<?php
$arr = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'funny',
    1 => 'haha',
    2 => 'lol'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'cat',
    1 => 'tabby',
    2 => 'kitty',
    3 => 'puss'
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'war',
    1 => 'fighting'
  )
);

$string = "funny cat fighting";

$words = explode(' ', $string, 3);

$result = [];
foreach ($arr[0] as $a) {
    if (!in_array($words[0], $arr[0])) {
        $a = $words[0];
    }
    foreach ($arr[1] as $b) {
        if (!in_array($words[1], $arr[1])) {
            $b = $words[1];
        }
        foreach ($arr[2] as $c) {
            if (!in_array($words[2], $arr[2])) {
                $c = $words[2];
            }

            if (!in_array($a.' '.$b.' '.$c, $result)) {
                $result[] = $a.' '.$b.' '.$c;
            }
        }
    } 
}

print_r($result);
```

**Result:** https://3v4l.org/7rEsh

```
Array
(
    [0] => funny cat war
    [1] => funny cat fighting
    [2] => funny tabby war
    [3] => funny tabby fighting
    [4] => funny kitty war
    [5] => funny kitty fighting
    [6] => funny puss war
    [7] => funny puss fighting
    [8] => haha cat war
    [9] => haha cat fighting
    [10] => haha tabby war
    [11] => haha tabby fighting
    [12] => haha kitty war
    [13] => haha kitty fighting
    [14] => haha puss war
    [15] => haha puss fighting
    [16] => lol cat war
    [17] => lol cat fighting
    [18] => lol tabby war
    [19] => lol tabby fighting
    [20] => lol kitty war
    [21] => lol kitty fighting
    [22] => lol puss war
    [23] => lol puss fighting
)
```

**Result** (using `dog`, instead of `cat`) https://3v4l.org/ICbZ6

```
Array
(
    [0] => funny dog war
    [1] => funny dog fighting
    [2] => haha dog war
    [3] => haha dog fighting
    [4] => lol dog war
    [5] => lol dog fighting
)
```

Don't forget to cite this answer on your homework ;p

Comment: np, glad to help